# How to edit a circle in angular-google-maps probably?

Tags: angular-google-maps

I have a circle in my map made with angular-google-maps. If I make the circle editable and move it somewhere and make it un-editable again, the circle is back at its initial state. So my question is, how to change the center and radius probably through the edit-functionality?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Btw. why got this question a downvote after ca. 2 years of its existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the issues section on their GitHub page I found a "solution". It works only until version `2.0.12` (http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.12/dist/angular-google-maps.js) after this version this functionality is broken.

**UPDATE:**
As requested here is a [Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1328) to the issue on GitHub. It was closed/fixed on the 27th Aug 2015.

Comment: you should link to the issue so we know when it gets fixed.